# How to simulate device turning via chrome devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, landscape-portrait, device-orientation

For studying purposes i'm trying to interact with a mobile version of a website using JS.

I'm clicking on buttons, filling fields, submiting forms and so on.

But there is a specific feature on this site that requires the mobile to be on vertical position and i'm not on a mobile, i'm on Chrome simulating a mobile user agent. In this case the website tells me to 'turn my device' to access the page, because the site thinks my device is on horizontal and it requires vertical.

Is there a way to simulate this using only JS code, to tell the site i'm on vertical position instead of horizontal ?

Comment: use chrome devtools for that

Comment: Are you using the device view in the dev tools? Just click on the "rotate" icon.

Comment: @str Is there a way to do it outside devtools, just using JS code ?

Comment: Screen orientation is not just some kind of flag that you can toggle. A screen is in landscape orientation if width > height.

Comment: @str It seems there is something else , not only width x height ; because even if i put the width > height, the website won't allow me to use the feature. It only works if i use Devtools, clicking on 'Toogle Device Bar' ; but i'm trying to simulate this without Devtools